# shell script to insert tag in to xml?

Tags: bash, shell

i have an xml

```
<Data>  

<employee>
  <name>emp1</name>
  <id>1</id>
</employee>

</Data>
```

lets say i have template in which i change value and add in to previous xml

```
<employee>
 <name>##name##</name> 
 <id>##empid##</id>
<employee>
```

i replace original value with ##name## and ##empid## and put in original xml
**name=emp2
eid=2**
so after that it sud be

```
<Data>  
<employee>
  <name>emp1</name>
  <id>1</id>
</employee>
<employee>
  <name>emp2</name>
  <id>2</id>
</employee> 

</Data>
```

i tried getting line no to insert tags

```
line=$(cat  data.xml | grep -n '</Data>' | grep -o '^[0-9]*')
```

and

tried to put text in to original xml using

```
sed $line\ i\<text to be insert in original xml>
```

but it gives some error with xml content ,help will be appriciated ,as i am new to shell script

Comment: Please capitalize conventionally.

Comment: The syntax for the substitute command in sed is (basically) `sed s/pattern/new-value/ file-name`

Comment: I'd give an xinclude solution if I could figure out what exactly you want. The 3rd sample doesn't follow from the first two AFACT.

Comment: @cdarke i dont want to substitute ,i want to insert and we can do with sed using sed <linenumber>i/content filename

Comment: @ormaaj 1st sample is original xml  ,,  2 nd is template where i will change ##name## ,##empid## and add in to original xml and would look like 3rd sample which i posted

Comment: So what is the error you get?

Comment: Where are you storing the values you're using to generate/populate your xml? In a file? Which layout has his file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xmlstarlet` to update your `template.xml`(which is ill-formed)

```
$ cat template.xml 
<employee>
 <name>##name##</name> 
 <id>##empid##</id>
</employee>

$ xmlstarlet ed -u //name -v emp2 -u //id -v 2 template.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<employee>
  <name>emp2</name>
  <id>2</id>
</employee>
```